# How can I split information in a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code. What it should do is open the file called example.txt in the same directory and it should only print out the first word of a big list.

```
with open('example.txt') as file:
    line = 'example.txt'
important_info = line.split()
print(important_info[0])
```

I'm pretty sure I messed up but I don't know how.

I first coded this and it worked

```
acc = ('info blah bloh blrjejw bfwe tee')
tui = acc.split()
print(tui[0])
```

In the code I showed above it only prints the first word for one line. But I want something that can do over 100 lines quickly. T think I'm close.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file:

```
with open('example.txt') as file:
    line = file.read()
important_info = line.split()
print(important_info[0])
```

Comment: I ran this code but it only outputed the first line in the document. It didn't work for the rest

Answer (score 0):

Want to make sure I understand- you want this program to read the first line of a file and print the first word right?

You're on the right track. You're accidentally splitting on the name of the file rather than it's file contents- you're missing the code that reads the contents of the file.

To explain your code:

```
with open('example.txt') as file:
    line = 'example.txt'
important_info = line.split()
print(important_info[0])
```

( important_info is a list containing just the filename i.e. ['example.txt'] so printing the first element would just be the string example.txt )

Something like this would work (reading the first line, splitting it by whitespace so that it's a list of words and then printing the first word in that list)

```
 f = open("example.txt", "r")
 print(f.readline().split()[0])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.